# Multiproccessing twitter api calls using python

Tags: python, twitter

I want to do multiproccesing on twitter search API.
I have got the code below and it do 1 call every time instead of multiproccesing.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from twitter import *

config = {}
exec(compile(open("config.py", "rb").read(), "config.py", 'exec'), config)
twitter = Twitter(
    auth=OAuth(config["access_key"], config["access_secret"], config["consumer_key"], config["consumer_secret"]))


def twitterSearch(word):
    tweetsWithWord = twitter.search.tweets(q=word, count=100)
    print(tweetsWithWord)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(8):
        p = Process(target=twitterSearch, args=('racist',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Please kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows

Comment: The issue is that you create a loop and spawn a single process within that loop each time, rather than start all processes at once. But I've realised I don't think I know enough about the API you're using to give you an answer; I don't know what you're trying to do or what's being returned. In terms of Windows, I found that `p.join()` could cause issues in itself because there is no `os.fork()` so removed it.

Comment: I believe what you need is multi-threading not multiproccessing. However, the main issue of current code is [join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue.join) which will waits until the process be completed. You could use process [pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to have a continuous stream of results for your search term. I don't know the package you're working with, but i do know that both [twython](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/) can use twitter's streaming API.

In any case, you'll need to process each and every tweet that comes up your stream when it arrives, and you can use processes/threads at that stage if needed.

Code example for streaming:

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from twython import TwythonStreamer
from requests.exceptions import ChunkedEncodingError

CONSUMER_KEY = 'AAA'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'BBB'
ACCESS_KEY = 'CCC'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'DDD'


class TwitterStream(TwythonStreamer):

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret, tqueue):
        self.tweet_queue = tqueue
        super(TwitterStream, self).__init__(consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret)

    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            self.tweet_queue.put(data)

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        #print(status_code)
        #with open(logfile,'a') as f:
        #        f.write(time.asctime(time.gmtime()) + ' ' + status_code + '\n')
        # Want to stop trying to get data because of the error?
        # Uncomment the next line!
        # self.disconnect()
        pass


def stream_tweets(tweets_queue,track):
    # Input your credentials below
    consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY
    consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
    token = ACCESS_KEY
    token_secret = ACCESS_SECRET
    try:
        stream = TwitterStream(consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret, tweets_queue)
        stream.statuses.filter(track=track) 
    except ChunkedEncodingError:
        # Sometimes the API sends back one byte less than expected which results in an exception in the
        # current version of the requests library
        stream_tweets(tweet_queue)


def process_tweets(tweets_queue, reply_dict, api, logfile):
    while True:
        twt = tweets_queue.get()
        # Do something with the tweet
        # You can start a new thread for actually proccessing each tweet
        tweets_queue.task_done()


tweet_queue = Queue()
track = 'whatever you want to filter by' # Search terms go here
Thread(target=stream_tweets, 
            args=(tweet_queue, track,), 
            daemon=True).start()
process_tweets(tweet_queue, reply_dict, api, logfile)
```

Comment: I did @MusicGindos